# Unlinked libc.so.6

Tags: linux, arch-linux, glibc

I unlinked libc.so.6 by running

```
$ sudo unlink /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

To fix it, I booted ubuntu on an usb stick and tried to link it again. The problem is I don't know the version of libc and can't file any `libc-*.so` file.

How can I find the correct file to fix this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arch seems to be using GNU libc, which is generally the default for most Linux distributions.](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/glibc/) As of this writing, the current version seems to be 2.35-3.

By taking a listing of the Arch package contents, I see:

```
$ unzstd < glibc-2.35-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst |tar tvf -  |grep libc.so
-rw-r--r-- root/root       255 2022-03-20 22:45 usr/lib/libc.so
-rwxr-xr-x root/root   2463384 2022-03-20 22:45 usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Unfortunately it looks like `/usr/lib/libc.so.6` is not a link but the actual library on Arch, so you'll have to make sure Ubuntu has `zstd` installed (`sudo apt-get install zstd`), then download Arch's `glibc-2.35-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst` (e.g. using the "Download from mirror" link on the Arch package info page linked above) to somewhere Ubuntu can access it, then do something like this:

```
$ unzstd < glibc-2.35-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst |tar xvf -  usr/lib/libc.so.6
$ sudo mv usr/lib/libc.so.6 <the mount location of your Arch root in Ubuntu>/usr/lib/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the issue! I was really stuck trying to find a libc file to link, as all solutions I saw were based on that.